# Configuring /graphicspath in latex for parent folders

Tags: graphics, latex, sublimetext3, miktex

I've been trying to use /graphicspath in latex to add some figures to a document, but it doesn't seem to be able to go to parent directories and find the folder.

For example, the main .tex file is stored in

`Parent/Write UP`

And the graphics in

```
Parent/Graphs
```

The latex code I'm trying to use

```
\graphicspath{{../Graphs/}}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{anything.png}
\end{document}
```

When I build or type the includegraphics nothing comes up, and errors saying that file isn't found.

When I put the graphs folder into the Write UP folder as

`Parent/Write UP/Graphs` 
And run this as latex:

```
\graphicspath{{/Graphs/}}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{anything.png}
\end{document}
```

I'm able to see all the graphics.

I'm using Sublimetext V 3.11, Build 3176 with MikTex

Comment: Can you show your .log file?

Answer (score 0):

I followed what you did and it worked for me. If you're compiling via the terminal check if you're in the right folder. You need to compile your main.tex from inside the `Parent/Write UP` if you want this to work:

```
\graphicspath{{../Graphs/}}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{anything.png}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm in the correct folder and it's not working for me.